# Parametric integral over polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

> For $x \in [0,1]$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$ let
>   $$f_k(x) = \int_0^x (x-t)^{k-1} \, (1-t)^k \, \mathrm{d}t $$

According to Mathematica it holds:

$$f_1(x) = -\frac{x^2}{2} +x$$

$$f_2(x) = \frac{x^4}{12}-\frac{x^3}{3} +\frac{x^2}{2}$$

$$f_3(x) = -\frac{x^6}{60} + \frac{x^5}{10}  - \frac{x^4 }{3} + \frac{x^3}{3}$$

I believe that for all $ \in \mathbb{N}$ the integral $f_k(x)$ is a polynomial in $x$. Unfortunately, I am not able to obtain a usable closed-form solution to $f_k(x)$. Mathematica gives only gives some hypergemetric function for general $k$.

Does anybody know some trick to compute a formula for the polynomial for general $k \in \mathbb{N}$? Thank you!

Comment: I guess try $y\equiv x-t$

Answer (score 1):

We have $$f_k(x) = \int_0^x (x-t)^{k-1} \, (1-t)^k \, dt$$ for $x\in [0,1]$ and $k\in \mathbb{N}$. Let $$p(t)=(1-t)^k\implies p'(t)=-k(1-t)^{k-1}$$ and $$q'(t)=(x-t)^{k-1}\implies q(t)=-\frac1k(x-t)^k$$ So by integration by parts, $$f_k(x)=[p(t)q(t)]_0^x-\int_0^xp'(t)q(t)\, dt=A+kI$$ where $$I=\int_0^x ((1-t)(x-t))^{k-1}\,dt$$ and $$A=\left[-\frac1k((1-t)(x-t))^k\right]_0^x=0-\left(-\frac1k((1-0)(x-0)^k\right)=\frac{x^k}k.$$ I think this explains the final term of each $f_{k\in\mathbb{N}}(x)$.

However, I don't think $\int_0^x ((1-t)(x-t))^{k-1}\,dt$ could be written in terms of elementary functions since there is no closed form of an integral of the form $$\int (at^2+bt+c)^d\, dt$$ for real numbers $a,b,c,d$ that doesn't use hypergeometric functions.

If you are interested, here is the link to the computation of $I$: `http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+(t-(1%2Bt)x%2Bx%5E2)%5E(k-1)`.